# Why can't a function called inside another one get access to outer function's scope?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Why are functions scoped at definition, making a code like this one not work?

```
function foo() {
    var text = "abc";
    bar(); // ReferenceError because bar cannot access foo's local variables
}

function bar() {
    console.log(text); // Calling bar inside foo does not grant it access to foo's local variables 
}

foo();
```

I can only imagine bar working if we define a global variable named *text*.

I understand that the only way we could have access to a function's local variable would be through creating a closure like this one

```
function foo() {
    var text = "abc";
    return function() {
        console.log(text);
    }
}

bar = foo();
bar();
```

Well, I like to think that I understand JavaScript scoping (including ES6's block scoping).
So I guess my question is, why can't a function called inside another one have access to the outer function's scope as if it were defined inside it? What would be the disadvantage of that?

Comment: This seems like it would require writing functions with undeclared variables to be filled in later by the surrounding calling context. That seems to me (admittedly, not a language designer) like just a really confusing alternative to passing in arguments. In other words, functions already *have* a way to accept values from the calling context: arguments. It seems confusing to have two different ways to supply just values (e.g., imagine needing to document what arguments a function accepts *and* what vars it expects the calling context to declare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is called "Dynamic Scoping" and it is not possible in JavaScript. The way JavaScript and just about everything now does it is called "Lexical Scoping".  You can google both of those to get a lot of discussion on the topic.

There have been languages in the past that tried out dynamic scoping. Really, though, it was determined a long time ago that dynamic scoping just makes it too hard to reason about programs and figure out what is going on.

With lexical scoping you can tell just by looking which "version" of a variable you're using, but with with dynamic scoping that might depend on who's calling you, and that makes it really hard for you to do anything using those variables.